# C++ STRUCT doesn't store values

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a problem, I made basic structure

```
struct TRADEBOT_ITEM
{
    BYTE Slot;
    BYTE Cat;
    BYTE Id;
    BYTE LVL;
};
struct TRADEBOT_BUFFS
{
    short BUFFID;
    short Duration;
};

struct TRADEBOT_INVENTORY
{
    short itemId;
    BYTE level;
    BYTE opt;
    BYTE opt2;
    BYTE opt3;
    BYTE NewOption;
    BYTE Socket[5];
    int Expiration;

};
struct TRADEBOT_REQ
{
    short itemId;
    BYTE level;
    BYTE opt;
    BYTE opt2;
    BYTE opt3;
    BYTE NewOption;
    BYTE Socket[5];
};
struct TRADEBOT_MIX
{
    TRADEBOT_INVENTORY m_Inventory[64];
    TRADEBOT_REQ    m_Req[64];
    int ReqCnt;
};
struct TRADEBOT_DATA
{
    BYTE ID;
    BYTE Class;
    BYTE SPAWN;
    BYTE map;
    BYTE X;
    BYTE Y;
    BYTE Dir;
    BYTE Vip;
    WORD Strength;
    WORD Dexterity;
    WORD Vitality;
    WORD Energy;
    WORD Leadership;
    int ZEN;
    char Name[10];
    TRADEBOT_ITEM m_Item[9];
    TRADEBOT_BUFFS m_Buffs[5];
    TRADEBOT_MIX m_Mix[142];
};
```

which is later used as

```
std::map<int, TRADEBOT_DATA> m_BotData;
```

then I try to read info from a file and save the info from fil in the structure

```
            this->m_BotData[ID].m_Mix[ID].m_Req[cntr].itemId = ITEMGET(cat,idx);


            Token = GetToken();
            this->m_BotData[ID].m_Mix[ID].m_Req[cntr].level = TokenNumber;

            Token = GetToken();
            this->m_BotData[ID].m_Mix[ID].m_Req[cntr].opt = TokenNumber;

            Token = GetToken();
            this->m_BotData[ID].m_Mix[ID].m_Req[cntr].opt2 = TokenNumber;

            Token = GetToken();
            this->m_BotData[ID].m_Mix[ID].m_Req[cntr].opt3 = TokenNumber;

            Token = GetToken();
            this->m_BotData[ID].m_Mix[ID].m_Req[cntr].NewOption = TokenNumber;

            Token = GetToken();
            this->m_BotData[ID].m_Mix[ID].m_Req[cntr].Socket[0] = TokenNumber;

            Token = GetToken();
            this->m_BotData[ID].m_Mix[ID].m_Req[cntr].Socket[1] = TokenNumber;

            Token = GetToken();
            this->m_BotData[ID].m_Mix[ID].m_Req[cntr].Socket[2] = TokenNumber;

            Token = GetToken();
            this->m_BotData[ID].m_Mix[ID].m_Req[cntr].Socket[3] = TokenNumber;

            Token = GetToken();
            this->m_BotData[ID].m_Mix[ID].m_Req[cntr].Socket[4] = TokenNumber;

            this->m_BotData[ID].m_Mix[ID].ReqCnt++;
            cntr++;
```

and the structure stays blank, no info is written it it. And I have no idea why.

also if I change the value `TRADEBOT_MIX m_Mix[142];` to `TRADEBOT_MIX m_Mix[143];` application crashes, also no idea why. Any ideas would be appreciated.

I am using Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Try running it in the debugger, stepping through it line by line, to see what really happens.

Comment: Also, how do you initialize `ID` and `cntr`?

Comment: ID is read from file cntr is int cntr = 0; I tried to debug it, it simply completes the lines like all is ok, but doesnt save any value.. and p.s if I change the value of m_Mix[142] to m_Mix[143] the application crashes and sais there is no source or dissambly available, this is making me confused

Comment: Add lots of asserts. For example, make sure `ID` is in range. Make sure `cntr` is in range. Also, use a reference to avoid having to search the map on each assignment. `TRADEBOT_MIX& botMix = this->mBotData[ID].mMix[ID]; `botMix.m_Req[cntr]....` or something like that. Also, how did you determine the structure stays blank?

Comment: Two points - using ID in both map and structure array for indexing may indicate an incorrect abstraction. Secondly, Are you checking if ID exceeds 142 in your code?

Comment: @kumar_m_kiran: I suspect that incorrect abstraction is probably why he's finding the data unmodified.

Comment: Do. Not. Assume. Log the address of the structure, and the value of `ID` and `cntr`, at the point of assignment. Assert that the assignment is being made in the very next line (write and read back). Log the address of the structure, and the value of `ID` and `cntr` at the point you are checking the structure contents. Assert that they are identical. Assert that the contents are identical immediately after writing them, and at the point you want to check them again. **Then tell us which assertion *exactly* failed**, and provide relevant code.

Comment: M_BotData is a map.  You haven't shown any code where you add an item into the map.

Comment: @GintersOzols It's a common situation on SO. You have a bug in your program, but all the code you posted is correct. Try posting more code. Remember the error is is just as likely be how you retrieve the saved information, not how you save it in the first place.

Comment: ok I have found out that it saved the values, only I was looking into wrong structure, Thank you very much for all your effort answering my problem, but one thing still exists, the crash `TRADEBOT_MIX m_Mix[142];` to `TRADEBOT_MIX m_Mix[143];` causes crash in `this->m_BotData.insert(std::pair<int, TRADEBOT_DATA>(m_Bot.ID, m_Bot));` `m_Bot` is defined as `TRADEBOT_DATA m_Bot;` if the size  `m_Mix[142]` is 142 or lower then it works good, once i increase the value it crashes..

Comment: What are `TRADEBOT_ITEM` and `TRADEBOT_BUFFS` ? (please post their declaration in an edit).

Comment: Your `TRADEBOT_DATA` is a big structure, 255120 bytes. With 143 `TRADEBOT_MIX` instead of 142,  maybe you cross a size limit (I'm not sure about this). It also depends on whether you're allocating dynamically or on the stack, and the stack size.

Comment: I have a structure that is MUCH more bigger, but its not using std::map, maybe thats the problem, does std::map has any limitations?